# Does a global maximum within a specified domain have to be a critical point? Or can it just be the highest point within that domain?

Tags: calculus

Does the global maximum within a specified domain have to be a critical point? Or can it just be the highest point within that domain?

Comment: What about $-|x|$ it has no derivative in $0$ yet maximum. So regularity matters in this question. Also you need two sided interval, else $x$ reach a max at $1$ on $[0,1]$ without being a critical point.

Comment: @zwim is right. And it has to be an interior point of the domain. If it is on the boundary, literally everything can happen.

Comment: Also $x$ on domain $[1,2]$. The global maximum is $x=2$.

Comment: @Meowdog, I agree, this happens often when using Lagrange multipliers, when there are no critical points, people often forget to check the boundary.